# Send oraclize query with variables

Tags: solidity

I need to send a solidity request, which looks like this:

```
validId[oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(http://myIp.something/wallet_check.json?wallet=".toSlice().concat(toString(msg.sender).toSlice()).toSlice().concat(").white_listed".toSlice())   )] = msg.sender;
```

However, conversion toString return unreadable string, which is probably why oracle can't handle the request. How do i convert address to string or go around the conversion?

code for `toString()`:

```
function toString(address x) returns (string) {
bytes memory b = new bytes(20);
for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
return string(b);
```

}